# Структура базы данных для тестирования знаний

Tags: база-данных, структуры

Не понимаю, как формируется структура базы данных.
По моему представлению вот такое:

1. Таблица -- Ученик

   - ID_uchenik
   - Name
   - Surname
   - Class

(Эти поля Name и Surname будут использоваться для входа в систему)

2. Таблица -- Вопросы

   - Id_question
   - Id_test
   - question
   - answer1
   - answer2
   - answer3
   - answer4
   - correct_answer
   - question_number
3. Таблица -- Тесты

   - id_test
   - id_uchenik

Верно спроектирована структура базы данных?

P.S. Планирую использовать asp.net для создания системы с видеоуроками и тестирования знаний... Пока можно очень простейшую систему...

Comment: 1. То есть любой ученик может зайти под любыми учетными данными.  2. А если больше 4-х вопросов?

Comment: 1. Да, любой ученик может зайти в систему, используя свои имя и фамилию.
2. Нет, достаточно 4 вопроса.
P.S. Не собираюсь писать крутую систему.

Comment: Но я знаю имя и фамилию моего друга, над которым я могу подшутить и пройти тест за него неправильно. Ну это такое. Таблицу с вопросами я бы сделал более универсальной. К примеру: id, test_id, answer. То есть для каждого теста есть наборы ответов. Также нужно предусмотреть тип теста (можно выбирать один ответ или несколько)

Comment: Согласен с вашим утверждением. Но такое не пройдет в отдельно взятой школе.
Вот и именно я и спрашивал про структуру базы данных для тестирования знаний учащихся... Мне не нужно слишком большая база данных, а достаточно 3-4 таблицы.

Comment: И еще, чтобы вам более понятно данная проблема.
Сам работаю в школе для глухих детей. Решил как-то немного автоматизировать учебный процесс. Уроки дублируются жестовым языком.
Решил написать обучающую систему (видео-уроки) и систему тестирования знаний(вопросы и ответы текстом дублируются видео на жестовом языке).
Надеюсь, уже после разъяснения уже стало понятно.

Comment: Я вижу некий test_id, а где таблица, в которой этот test_id primary key, т.е. которая и должна зваться "тесты". А ваша третья таблица - это видимо "оценки за тесты" или что то в этом роде, только самой оценки нет. А вообще думаю нужна "ответы учеников" где id_вопроса, id_уреника, ответ_ученика

Comment: Вот и поэтому спрашиваю... Думал, что еще третье поле является лишним, а именно -- count_question

Comment: Совет: не нужно писать новую систему, возьмите moodle.

Comment: @GhostBasenji Стоп. так еще и количество вопросов ... В вопросе поля count_question кстати нет. И зачем хранить кол-во если есть сами вопросы. На самом деле, невозможно ничего посоветовать не зная постановки задачи.

Comment: @rvs знаю про moodle. Но неохота возиться с этой системой. Но меня интересовало простая система со данной структурой базы данных. В данном случае мне видится более удобная связка: MSSQL(можно PostgreSQL или SQLite) + Asp.net.

Comment: Немного поразмыслил над структурой базы данных и нашел еще почти такой же вопрос: Система тестирования 2. Как правильней спроектировать БД?. Уже полностью решил, сильно помогли ответы вышеприведенного указания на этот вопрос.

Comment: А теперь осталось узнать, как произвести подсчет правильных и неправильных ответов.
И еще, в случае успешного решения вышеупомянутого вопроса, уже можно считать вопрос закрытым.

Answer (score 2):

Если на каждый тест произвольное кол-во вариантов ответа и правильным Является **один** ответ (выбрать можно только один), то как-то так:

У нас есть набор набор вопросов и набор ответов, из наборов формируем отдельное Задание. Оно состоит из одного вопроса, и произвольного кол-ва вариантов ответов. Для данного конкретного Задания, конкретный ответ может быть правильным или нет. Ученик отвечает на Задание выбрав один из Ответов.

- вопрос (номер, текст)
- вариант_ответа (номер, текст)
- задание (номер, вопрос.номер)
- задание_ответ(задание.номер, вариант_ответа.номер, правильный_ответ?)
- ученик (номер, фио, логин, пароль)
- ответ (ученик.номер, задание.номер, вариант_ответа.номер, дата)